# PostGIS efficient DISTINCT point filtering

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to write a query to efficiently grab all non overlapping points from within a given Polygon within a certain Geohash precision.

Things to note:

- I have many ***many*** millions of rows.
- I have spatial indexes on
  the geoms.
- I have indexes on the timestamps.

The generic query, which also works **great** and is **very fast** even with many millions of points.

```
SELECT * FROM points WHERE
ST_Contains(polygon, location)
AND timestamp >= somedate AND timestamp <= somedate
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
```

Now lets say I want to remove overlapping points to a certain precision I would do this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ST_GeoHash(ST_SetSRID(location, 4326), 9)) 
* FROM points WHERE
ST_Contains(polygon, location)
AND timestamp >= somedate AND timestamp <= somedate
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
```

The results are what I am looking for. Filtering out overlapping points.

However, EXPLAIN shows the Unique costing somewhere around 78000, and running the query itself is painfully slow.

Does anyone have any experience or good ideas to **efficiently** (sub 1 second) filter overlapping points in the database layer?

Comment: I believe both of your queries wouldn't work because of duplicate WHERE clause.

Comment: Oh crap, that is just a type-o here on my part. The queries don't actually look like that Editing...

Comment: Can you post your EXPLAIN output as well? And do you want your LIMIT to be run _before_ or _after_ your DISTINCT. If it is before, you can save time creating a subquery outputting your points fist, including the LIMIT.